# docker set two value for the host name inside container

Tags: docker

As we can set hostname using docker run command but the behavior is different once the container is up there is two value for the host.

Docker run command.

```
docker run --rm --name alpine -dit --hostname "pmy.test.com" alpine
```

Here is the host's file

`172.17.0.3` contain two values **`pmy.test.com`** and **`pmy`**

[image]

so when I run some application like ejabberd or other application which depends on hostname so its get **pmy** which is incorrect in my case.

Where there is only one value for the hostname in my system (Ubuntu).

Is there any way to set one name for the host?

Why docker makes partition of hostname after **.** (dot)?

Can we disable this behavior of docker?

> --hostname    The hostname a container uses for itself. Defaults to the container’s name if not specified.

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services